How to do object detection for 1 object in the image, with 3 possible classes (in a custom dataset)
I am new to deep learning, I hope you will lead me because I have been stuck for a week. I am trying to build a model for identifying a single object in the image.
So, I made my custom dataset, which looks like this:

I have 3 objects e.g dog, cat, cow. (So only 3 pictures which are being pasted)
Object is randomly placed around some (on top of it) background picture.
My dataset has three folders -> Train (has images (jpgs) and labels (txt)). Test with similar and Val with similar.
In my labels, I save the class (0,1,2) and where the object is pasted, so it's coordinates.

Now, I want to do my CNN architecture.
I want the model to have 2 outputs:

one for class probabilities (same size as the number of objects chosen, i.e. 3)
another for bounding box regression (of size 4, due to the box coordinates x,y,w,h)

How do I go on in creating the model? What if I want regularization. Is there an online repo about this? or an article. I can't find something which does training for one object.
